# The JAVA application does not want to run via the command line (mvn spring-boot: run), but it works in IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I run the application in IDEA via mvn spring-boot: run, everything works fine. But as soon as I run .bat with mvn spring-boot: run command, the application doesn't work.
Need help. What could be the problem?
Moreover, this code worked earlier. What could be the problem is not clear to me. Reviewed a lot of information.

UPD. I tried to run it on another computer via the command line, everything started. I guess something is blocking spring-boot. Most likely the problem is not with the code.

```
2021-08-24 19:29:26.679  INFO 17856 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.Application                  : Starting Application on DESKTOP-7AMEB3A with PID 17856 (D:\renzo\target\classes started by Kirov in D:\renzo)
2021-08-24 19:29:26.682  INFO 17856 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-24 19:29:26.801  INFO 17856 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@19bf5f45: startup date [Tue Aug 24 19:29:26 MSK 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-08-24 19:29:28.555 ERROR 17856 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.example.Application
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:414) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:254) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(Abs....

2021-08-24 19:29:28.558  INFO 17856 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@19bf5f45: startup date [Tue Aug 24 19:29:26 MSK 2021]; root of context hierarchy
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.293 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-24T19:29:28+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This my pom

```
 <groupId>mywebparsingeasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>mywebparsingeasy</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.4</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-alpha-3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>mywebparsingeasy</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.example.parsing.Application</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
          <configuration>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <mainClass>com.example.parsing.Application</mainClass>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.example.parsing.Application</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: why do you need a bat file for one command

Comment: you can probably do `mvn clean package` and then `java -jar ./target/file.jar`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: is docker an option? I think you are having an issue with your local java version or the spring boot version itself.

Comment: You are mixing different spring boot versions. Your parent defines `2.0.3.RELEASE` second `spring-boot-starter-parent` (version: 2.5.4) with a pom type (which is btw  simply wrong. Furthermore defining the spring-boot-maven-plugin with version `2.2.4.RELEASE`..and much more important defining the plugins in pluginManagement. Remove the maven-jar-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin and all other plugins defined. Use one version of spring boot and define the spring-boot-maven-plugin outside pluginManagement....

Comment: If that code worked earlier you should check your version control what you have changed...